# How can I synchronize all PDFs from one directory with Dropbox?

Tags: rsync, find

I want to synchronize all the PDFs from one directory (my Zotero library) to Dropbox. Finally, I want to have a list of all the PDFs, not the directory names.

I successfully synchronized all my PDFs with the following command:

```
rsync -az --include="*/" --include="*.pdf" --exclude="*" \ 
--prune-empty-dirs /zotero /dropbox
```

I think I can easily set up a `cron` job to redo that task every day, but haven't tried that yet.

But now my folder on Dropbox still has all the directories with the PDFs in it (e.g. `6NVTACJH > xyz.pdf`)

**My problem:**
I would love to only have all the pdfs listed in one directory. Following an [advice](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/153112-rsync-multiple-directories-into-single-directory-remote.html) from the web, I tried to `find` all pdfs and create a hardlink.

But this command does not work yet.

```
ln $( find -name="*.pdf" -type f - links 1 ) /dropbox
```

Can you please help me with that last command?